# What ist the reason for the error message "Error: FUNCTION 'NUCLEUS_ASCII' already exists. (state=X0Y68,code=30000)"?

Tags: cmd, hive, cygwin, derby, hive-metastore

There is output the following error information:

> Error: FUNCTION 'NUCLEUS_ASCII' already exists. (state=X0Y68,code=30000)
> org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaException: Schema initialization FAILED! Metastore state would be inconsistent !!
> Underlying cause: java.io.IOException : Schema script failed, errorcode 2
> Use --verbose for detailed stacktrace.
> *** schemaTool failed ***

*Hive* and *Hadoop* daemons are running fine. I ran *Hive* services after the *Metastore* services via *Cygwin*. I deleted all the *Metastore* `db` directories. Then I am facing also the same issue mentioned above after running the commands below.

In Windows command prompt window:

```
C:\hadoop_new\db-derby-10.14.2.0\bin\startNetworkServer -h 0.0.0.0
```

In *Cygwin* terminal window:

```
$HIVE_HOME/bin/schematool -dbType derby -initSchema
```

**Error:**

```
hive > FAILED: HiveException java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient
```

Answer (score 5):

Solution :
Go to below directory:
C:\hadoop_new\apache-hive-3.1.2\scripts\metastore\upgrade\derby\hive-schema-3.1.0.derby.sql
comment the 'NUCLEUS_ASCII' function and 'NUCLEUS_MATCHES' function
rerun schematool -dbType derby -initSchema, then everything goes well!

Comment: Thanks @Abhay. In my case, I am using Ubuntu 16.04. I deleted `metastore_db` from hive conf directory and then commented the two functions you suggested in `/usr/local/hive/scripts/metastore/upgrade/derby/hive-schema-3.1.0.derby.sql` file.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue. The error was because I attempted to start hive before establishing the schema.  Try the following:

```
 $mv metastore_db metastore_db.tmp
```

Now run your schema setup.

I found this solution [here](https://www.edureka.co/community/63178/error-function-nucleus-ascii-already-exists).